# Does an algorithm exist that generate copula when marginal distributions are available and stable distributed and correlation is not simple?

Tags: correlation, matlab, random-generation, copula

I have simulated data of a 4-dimensional random variable $(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)$. The individual pdfs of these random variables, i.e., $X_i$ where $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ turns out to be stable distributed with no mean and variance. Though I am able to use *fitdist* MATLAB COMMAND to fit these distributions to Weibull distribution and the marginals turn out to be more or less identical in terms of parameters.

My aim is to generate a copula so that I can use that interrelation rather than using the simulated data for further processing and calculations. For this I am using *copulafit* MATLAB Command but none of the given copula family there can simulate my data properly or even approximately.

The data that I am using is also not producing a simple bivariate correlation, it is somewhat like this:
[image: correlation data between any two random variable data]
Where should I seek help to generate such data, that can have correlation like as given in the figure.

Comment: Maybe *Mathematica*'s copulas have different options:  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CopulaDistribution.html.  If you need a parametric density, why not use a mixture distribution to approximate the underlying distribution?

Comment: What does the sample copula density look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape of the univariate marginal distributions does not matter, as each one has to be transformed to Uniform[0,1] by the inverse CDF (the probability integral transform, PIT) before a copula is fit. For flexible multivariate copulas, try vine copulas. An automated algorithm of model building and selection of Disssmann et al. (2013) is implemented as function `vinecop` in the [`rvinecopulib`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvinecopulib/index.html) package in R. Its building blocks are a rather wide range of bivariate copulas; perhaps some of those would fit your data. (Of course, this is not the only alternative.)

**Reference:** Dissmann, J. F., E. C. Brechmann, C. Czado, and D. Kurowicka (2013). Selecting and estimating regular vine copulae and application to financial returns. *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis, 59*(1), 52-69.